# in unity2d rigibody, will there be any performance cost when I set rigibody.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.dynamic even though it is already dynamic?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

in unity2d rigibody, will there be any performance cost when I set rigibody.bodyType to dynamic even though it is already dynamic, or set contraints to none even though it is already none?

Comment: Why are you trying to set things to what they already are?

Comment: Change rigibody mode in update, according to the state the character is in.